# NodeJS cluster global variables

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing

I need to have one common counter for all workers, and everyone could increase it, and that all workers know that the counter has been increased.
How can i do that ?
All workers can see only local variabless , and only static global variabless.

Comment: What do you mean by static global variables here?

Comment: This thread will help you https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this, you will want to use the `cluster` module available in Node.js to message between the workers and the master.

#### Example Code

Here is a working example I just put together. I am using the latest version of Node.js available on the official website (`9.3.0`).

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';
const COUNTER = 'COUNTER';


if (cluster.isMaster) {

  cluster.fork();
  cluster.fork();

  let counter = 0;

  cluster.on('message', (worker, msg, handle) => {
    if (msg.topic && msg.topic === INCREMENT) {
      // here we increment the counter
      counter++;
      for (const id in cluster.workers) {
        // Here we notify each worker of the updated value
        cluster.workers[id].send({
          topic: COUNTER,
          value: counter
        });
      }
    }
  });

} else if (cluster.isWorker) {

  console.log(`Worker id: ${cluster.worker.id}`);
  // Here is a function that requests the counter be updated in the master from a worker.
  function incrementCounter() {
    process.send({ topic: INCREMENT });
  }

  // A dummy timeout to call the incrementCounter function
  setTimeout(incrementCounter, 1000 * cluster.worker.id);

  // Handle the counter update
  process.on('message', (msg) => {
    if (msg.topic && msg.topic === COUNTER) {
      console.log(`${cluster.worker.id}/${process.pid}: ${msg.topic} ${msg.value}`);
    }
  });

}
```

#### Example Output

```
Worker id: 1
Worker id: 2
1/1632: COUNTER 1
2/6200: COUNTER 1
2/6200: COUNTER 2
1/1632: COUNTER 2
```

#### Official Documentation

[Here is the documentation for `worker.send(message[, sendHandle][, callback])`](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_worker_send_message_sendhandle_callback)

Comment: I need all to increase the same counter, and not everyone's own
For example:
1/1632: COUNTER 1
2/6200: COUNTER 2
2/6200: COUNTER 3
1/1632: COUNTER 4

Comment: The counter variable is stored in the master process in this example and notifies each worker when the counter is updated. If one worker sends a message to update the counter, the master updates it and then notified each worker. If you are looking for the exact memory location to be shared between different processes, this is not possible since Node.js is single-threaded. See the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566780/process-vs-thread-can-two-processes-share-the-same-shared-memory-can-two-thr for the differences in threads vs. forked processes.

Comment: @Inomezi Also, the example you gave in your comment is only sending the updated counter to a single worker, is that what you want? In your original question, you specified "all workers know that the counter has been increased"

Comment: For  example we have 2 workers. They should increase the counter to 10 and then stop. But both must increase the same counter, and not each of their own

Comment: @Inomezi Are you saying the counter should be increased for each worker? Your example shows a different counter number passed back to each worker `1`, `2`, `3`, then finally `4`. If that is the case, just remove `counter++` from my example and change `value: counter` in the message sent to the workers to be `value: ++counter`. Otherwise, the question will need to be updated in more detail (e.g. if this is the case, then all workers **would not** know the counter was increased).